# Crash with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared

Can someone explain to me why the crash here?

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct Teacher : std::enable_shared_from_this<Teacher> {
    struct Timetable;
    std::shared_ptr<Timetable> timetable;
    Teacher (int n) : timetable(std::make_shared<Timetable>(*this, n)) {}
};

struct Period {
    std::shared_ptr<Teacher> teacher;
    Period (const std::shared_ptr<Teacher>& t) : teacher(t) {}
};

struct Teacher::Timetable {
    Teacher& teacher;
    std::shared_ptr<Period> homeForm;
    Timetable (Teacher& t, int n) : teacher(t),  // Assume something is done with n.
        homeForm( std::make_shared<Period>(teacher.shared_from_this()) ) {}  // Crashes.
//      homeForm( std::make_shared<Period>(std::shared_ptr<Teacher>(&teacher)) ) {}  // Also crashes.
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Teacher> teacher = std::make_shared<Teacher>(3);
}
```

Isn't `teacher.shared_from_this()` allowed here since `std::shared_ptr<Teacher> teacher` is a shared_ptr already?  If not, how do I initialize `homeForm` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code calls `shared_from_this` before the `std::shared_ptr<Teacher>` is fully constructed. It somehow makes sense that the `Teacher` sub-object has to be constructed before the smart pointer is fully constructed.

If you change the code like this,

```
struct Teacher : std::enable_shared_from_this<Teacher> {
    struct Timetable;
    std::shared_ptr<Timetable> timetable;
    Teacher() {}
    void init(int n) { this->timetable = std::make_shared<Timetable>(*this, n); }
};

// Everything else unchanged

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Teacher> teacher = std::make_shared<Teacher>();
    teacher->init(3);
}
```

it will run fine.

Note that I'm not recommending this as a refactoring. Constructors should fully initialize objects whenever possible. Looking at your code, it seems to me that you might want to consider re-structuring it somewhat more radical. Do you really need all this cross-referencing shared pointers?

Comment: Basically, it's the `shared_ptr` constructor that sets the `weak_ptr` in the `enable_shared_from_this` base. So you need the whole `shared_ptr<T>` to be constructed - not just the `Teacher`.

Comment: Thanks. But in my actual program, the Teacher constructor has arguments that need to be passed to the Teacher::Timetable constructor. Which means that init needs to receive those arguments. I've updated my question. Is duplicating those arguments in main() the only way?  Or store those arguments in `Teacher` and then pass them to `init`, even though they are just temporary?

Comment: @prestokeys I don't see why you would have to pass them to the constructor at all. But I'll repeat that I am *not* advertising the use of an `init` function or this coding style in general.

Comment: @5gon12eder   Because the `init()` function is being used generically with `T` objects and the int paramenter is needed for `T == Teacher` but not needed for, say, `T == Student`.  I've written an adapted solution of yours, which passes the `3` in the `Teacher` constructor and stores it in `Teacher` so then it can be used in the `init` function.  Ugly, but I can't think of any other way to adapt your solution.